# iFrame with Https

Tags: iframe, https

We have an application working with https on parent company. Now our reseller want to hide the url of parent company to visitor. For this we try to create a HTML page that has iframe covering all content area of page and run our parent applciation within that iframe. All works well for us, but when we run the Child application over HTTPS, it give warning that some content within iFrame container page is non secure. Where as the parent application is working just fine, without any security warning. I mean all SSL are working independently but not over each other.

If I am not wrong this is exactly what facebook do with their apps over https. Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you iFrame non secure content on SSL page, or Secure content on non SSL page, this error will alwaus show, your only solution is to secure all the pages .